# Double send of form when I refresh the page

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I avoid to submit again the form when I hit refresh of the browser? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), and the following article:

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=RedirectAfterPost

From the above link:

> PRG pattern can be rephrased like
>   this:
>
> - Never show pages in response to POST
> - Always load pages using GET
> - Navigate from POST to GET using    REDIRECT

Answer (score 0):

When a user first visits a form, create them a GUID (or other token that you can uniquely identify a specific user request) and send that through their entire journey on the form. When you commit to the database, add this to a field in there too. A quick check beforehand to see if it already exists and you're sorted. :)

**Edit:** These ways are not so much specific to when the user "hit[s] refresh on the browser", more as a way of stopping accidental duplicate entries anyway. As far as other useful threads, [this question asks and gets a few good replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218907/how-to-handle-multiple-submissions-server-side).