# Do we still need backup code for people who have javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript

I hear about it a bit in tutorials that I watch, that certain things won't work if javascript is disabled. Occasionally I see workarounds.

The question is, are these relevent? I can't imagine anyone not having a javascript enabled browser nowadays, except the most ancient of phones, and chances are your page won't render on them properly anyway.

Do people still bother to write backup code for javascript being disabled?

Edit: As a test, I turned javascript off. Facebook doesn't work.

Edit: I understand about visually impaired users, but do people care (harsh, yes) if their experience is buggy? Not to sound disrespectful, but not sticking to strict standards will alienate people using Internet Explorer 4 and 5 too, but we don't seem to care about them...?

Edit: Saying that people should do it seems like a very automatic response, considering how many people use JQuery and other groovy addon libraries.

Edit: I tried a bunch of fortune 500 sites, and so far about 70% of the ones I tried have broken

```
Dell
Walmart
Fedex
Intel
Coca Cola
```

Comment: It matters who your audience is.  You should be able to measure this using a web analytics tool.

Comment: Facebook also have a horrible reputation for handing privacy and are covered with Farmville. They are hardly a poster child for *how to build a quality website*.

Comment: Hmm, I had to enable Javascript to be able to reply to your comment... Do you think most developers on this site actually DO write workarounds?

Comment: I'm more concerned with building quality products then performing analysis of how many other people are.

Comment: If you ever become blind (which I obviously don't wish), and look back at your question, you'll probably hate yourself.

Comment: @SLC I'm curious; if you were going to ignore the advice of the community and accept the answer you wanted to hear, why bother asking the question in the first place?

Comment: We all shall be honest then. The decision should be based on business value not "research for perfection". So does the law force me to do so? As of now, I don't think so. Then as a businessman I must compare the cost of supporting user with javascript disabled with the cost of not having them as customers. I should also compare this to all other features I could add and see the potential increase in revenues. From the response of Gary Willoughby, we already see that excepted maybe for some specific population targetting, JS disabled browser is not a major concern anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Support for JavaScript-disabled web sites a nice thought, but not of much help, and of questionable value, IMHO

It is almost impossible to design a robust website without java script, and those that disable JS, for whatever reason, probably don't expect much of a user experience.  So if you are coding for that 1% of the population, you have no choice.  But for the majority of us, it is a given that JS is there.  Accessibility is a different issue, with its own challenges.  When I was doing web sites for Hewlett-Packard, they had to meet strict accessibility standards, and it was tough to create anything more than very basic web pages.  I wouldn't wish that on anybody.

Comment: That is just plain rubbish. The simpler something is, the more robust it tends to be. JavaScript almost always reduces simplicity.

Comment: "The simpler something is, the more robust it tends to be" .. huh. Like c++ hey .. hyper robust .. so simple to learn. That is why so many people have qualifications in c++ you know

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say @gerdi, C++ *is* pretty robust, and pretty simple, and heaps of people do have qualifications in it.

Comment: I usually have disabled JavaScript because I don't like advertisement. It seems most of it only works with JavaScript. I don't think only 1% blocks / tries to block advertisement.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, we still need backup code for people who have JavaScript disabled.

- JavaScript is often used to do things that break in screen readers (so many screen reader users disable it) or to cause changes to appear out of sight of a screen magnifier.
- JavaScript is still one of the biggest attack vectors to exploit security holes in browsers.
- Add-ons such as [No-Script](http://noscript.net/) are increasing in popularity.
- Search engines tend not to execute it (so you don't want to hide your content behind it)

I prefer to think of it as a [foundation](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) rather than backup.

> I understand about visually impaired users, but do people care (harsh, yes) if their experience is buggy?

Nasty people don't.

The law (in many jurisdictions) does.

> Not to sound disrespectful, but not sticking to strict standards will alienate people using Internet Explorer 4 and 5 too, but we don't seem to care about them...?

IE 4/5 have:

- a smaller market share than users without JS
- many security holes
- no support from their own publisher

Comment: Yes they do, or yes it's important?

Comment: +1 for good link on foundation

Comment: +1: on JS being an attack vector. I was hit by a drive-by-download a few months ago because I didn't have NoScript installed in my Firefox browser. I'm always appreciative of smart JS programmers who account for people with JS disabled. The Honest Tea website is programmed properly. It fails gracefully when there is no JS or Flash. See this page for an example: http://www.honesttea.com/tea/plastic/mango_green/ (hehe, well, you'll have to disable your JS to see what I mean...)

Comment: Do they have a smaller market share than people with screenreaders though? I would say more people use outdated browsers than special screenreaders. You say "nasty people", but how certain are you that every webdeveloper on this site who uses JQuery makes sure their site is fully functional without it?

Comment: Yes, they do have smaller market share. More people do, but "outdated" is much wider then "IE 4/5". I'd be very surprised if everybody who used jQuery and SO produced quality sites (especially given some of the questions). Note that I didn't use the word "only" though.

Comment: So in answer to the original question, do you think people need to do it if they are getting by so well without? Especially with regard to fortune 500 companies.

Comment: How many of those companies have websites that actually matter to the company?

And, yes, people need to do it. For legal, moral and doing the best possible instead of "getting by".

Comment: Well, Dell, Fedex and Walmart probably do.

What legal and moral issues exist here anyway? My house doesn't have wheelchair access, but I am not discriminating against people, it just doesn't have one. I'm not actively excluding anyone. The effort it takes to fallback gracefully and test everything twice probably doesn't warrant it for the handful of people who would want to view your site with a screenreader, nevermind those that actually go on to do business with you.

Comment: You house is, presumably, not providing a service to the public. The effort it takes to fallback gracefully is not as much as some people seem to think.

Comment: I'm certainly going to check it out, you are talking sense. If the cost is minimal I'll try to be savvy in future projects :)

Comment: @Quentin..obviously depends on the project and team size but I tend to agree with SLC

Answer (score 14):

As a developer I no longer worry about 1% of users who turn off Javascript. It is too time consuming and development time is too expensive to waste on such nonsense. AJAX saves an incredible amount of bandwidth which turns directly into $$$ savings, which makes profits higher. If I lose one or two potential users of the site for every 100 users, those one or two lost users will cost a lot more in development than the potential income of they could ever bring in.

Try turning off Javascript and logging into Facebook, it becomes a very broken website after that. If it's good enough for Facebook, its good enough for me.

Comment: What's your basis for the 1% estimate? My experience indicates a much higher number.

Comment: I have javascript create a simple cookie on the users drive, then I have the server (via Perl scripts) read the cookie to see if it exists.  If Perl does not find the cookie I display a message above the navbar that this site needs javascript to run most of its functions.  Since I'm running a heavily used custom written discussion forum I record every click the users make on a site in a database and I record this cookie value as one of the fields.  Analyzing the data I find the cookie is missing between 1% and 2% on average.

Comment: Is your test website fully functional without JavaScript? Presumably, users that are too annoyed due to broken functionality simply left your site and never come back, so they count much lesser page views compared to JavaScript enabled users. Also is this 1% counting unique users or page views?

Answer (score 8):

I have a different opinion to many here. I don't think you necessarily should care in some scenarios, especially if your website is targeting a particular group of people or that it is going to mean a lot of work.

if you refer to:

http://visualrevenue.com/blog/2007/08/eu-and-us-javascript-disabled-index.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [visualrevenue.com](http://visualrevenue.com/media/uploaded_images/JavaScript-Disabled-735177.JPG))</sub>

You can see that year on year **more browsers than ever have Javascript enabled**, contrary to the other answers' claims. It was at 96.9% in 2007.

So you lose 3% of potential viewers, so what, your advertising campaign will do a lot more damage than that!

Comment: Those are statistics for W3Schools itself — a subset of users who think W3Schools is a good place to learn from is not a particularly useful sample.

Comment: Edit: Added a better analysis.

Comment: this really depends on your target audience. If you're catering to, say, military contractors, browser capabilities will typically be more severely restricted. We still have to support IE6 with no JS for this reason.

Comment: Agreed, that's why i said **some scenarios**. On the whole though, don't sweat it!

Comment: visualrevenue.com is blocked by uBlock Origin because it is a tracking server...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Especially when it comes to 508 and WCAG compliance. While the technologies to create accessible JavaScript are coming out of their infancy (see ARIA), developer's should still be coding sites in a way the does not require JavaScript.

http://www.w3.org/WAI/aria/faq

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/

Comment: On the other hand (not that I disagree), ARIA can actually work really well, and can provide *better* usability if exploited. People with disabilities who use screen reader systems and other assistive technologies are generally motivated to keep up-to-date, too.  It's definitely something to investigate for those wishing to maximize accessibility of their applications.

Comment: Much as there is motivation to upgrade, a copy of JAWS standard costs about 10 times more than Windows.

Answer (score 2):

All the other questions got most of the points covered, but I'll chime in with this: it's not a big deal to have your page(s) degrade gracefully in the absence of javascript. If you've got some super-whizzy ajax-infested real-time comet style app that really isn't going to work without javascript, you should at least render a nice message to the effect that javascript is required.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your audience and type of website.

For instance, a graphic artist portfolio will not be visited by blind people or people using text browsers. So in that case it's not so important to build nice degradable JS, expecially because it will most probably be used for graphic effects.

If, on the other hand you're developing a news website and you decide (for whatever reason) to dynamically load your news with JS then you should definitely make it degradable. Also, remember that the spiders of indexing engines may have difficulties in indexing content loaded with JS in your page.

At the end of the day, in most cases it's not so difficult to program the site so that it works without JS. If you're retrieving content dynamically you already have the server-side code to load the content, you just need to accomodate how the page is called.
Same thing for forms, you can send the content via AJAX or via a normal POST, the backend will be pretty much the same, so it's again easy to implement.

Of course, the problem is not even posed for JS code that is purely graphical.

Answer (score 1):

My recent experience:

My former supervisor claimed, in earnest, that because Google Analytics told us that "87% of our users have Java enabled and less than 3% are using IE6," that we didn't have to worry about supporting older browsers or users with JavaScript disabled.

Problem 1: Java is not JavaScript.

Problem 2: In order for Google Analytics to track a hit, the browser must have JavaScript enabled because the GA interface is a JS include. GA is not, and can not, be aware of users with JS disabled, which can potentially severely skew its reports.

Problem 3: one of our biggest customers requires that all engineers use IE6 with JS disabled.

Problem 4: The boss (at the time) didn't know how to read analytics reports.

If you want to know how important this support is to your business, a good place to start is the IIS logs. Just about everything related to the browser caps is stored by IIS. I regularly import the logs into SQL Server and run some basic reports from my admin site, which come in handy every time someone starts suggesting that we go crazy with the jQuery BS.

If you decide to start building complicated, script-dependent interfaces, be sure that your interface degrades gracefully and doesn't remove required functionality if JS is disabled.

Comment: My Apache doesn't have any "IIS logs". :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not merely a question of whether a browser is capable of executing javascript, but if a user has disabled it for some reason.

For example, you need to be aware of vison-impaired users. Such users might disable javascript, because the effects are confusing their screen reader software.