# form submit only one time

Tags: php, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing duplicate form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615813/preventing-duplicate-form-submissions)

I set a condition that is

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    //do some action
}
```

For the first time the condition is checked, it works fine but if the user refreshes the page it does the action 2nd time. How should I check?

Comment: Didn't understand your question ?

Comment: I think there must be thousand of answer for this on stackoverflow itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can unset your submit button after insert or update in database for e.g unset($_POST['btn_submit']);

Comment: If the page is refreshed, the browser will resubmit the data, and `$_POST` will be repopulated.

Comment: unset() destroys the specified variables.
Check this :http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: 1. User submits form data. 2. PHP populates `$_POST`. 3. PHP updates database. 4. PHP deletes data from `$_POST`. 5. User **resubmits form data** by refreshing. 5. PHP **repopulates** `$_POST` with the user submitted data. 6. PHP updates database. 7. PHP deletes data from `$_POST`.

Comment: Unsetting the variable does no good because it gets set again by the action of making the HTTP request! The script is running afresh!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent double post, by usage of browser-refresh, consider this solution.

[Preventing duplicate form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615813/preventing-duplicate-form-submissions)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Use [the Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

1. Browser makes POST request
2. Server modifies database and returns a Redirect response
3. Browser makes GET request
4. Server shows page in a 200 response

Refreshing will just reload the the page returned in step 4 without repeating step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the form processing could be split 3 steps:

- display form
- process data
- redirection to the results page (e.g. thank you page)

The redirection is done to avoid the form for being submitted again on refresh.
So, in your case, after the processing, you could redirect the user back to the same form again. If he refreshes the page, the form will not be submitted again, since the browser was redirected and the last action was a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

To do the actual redirecting in PHP, you could use the `header` function:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
   ...
   // redirect back to the form
   header("Location: form.php");
}
```

Comment: The `Location` HTTP response header takes an absolute URI, not a relative one. Don't depend on browser error correction. (At least one browser will redirect while complaining to the user about the error).

Comment: You're right. I checked the HTTP specs http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 and it requires an absolute URI. I didn't know that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh problem can be solved by redirecting the page after your operation completed succesfully

```
if(isset($_POST))
{ 
    //  do some action 


// redirect to same page so that values will not get posted again
header("location:samepage.php"); 
}
```

Comment: The `Location` HTTP response header takes an absolute URI, not a relative one. Don't depend on browser error correction. (At least one browser will redirect while complaining to the user about the error).